# Columnbased Databinding in .Net?

Tags: c#, data-binding, infragistics, business-objects

I am looking for a way to databind my objects columnbased.
So one object will be represented by a Column and not like normal binding where an object is represented by a row. At the moment I am using Infragistics UltraGrid and create a DataTable from my BusinessObjects on my own and use it as a DataSource for the Grid. But I don´t like that way because it does not use Databinding and doing updates to such a DataTable/View is painful. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What is the data? You *can* transpose data on-the-fly ([like so](http://groups.google.co.uk/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/browse_thread/thread/ae1251a6855b9254/29ed401fdfb1b4c1?lnk=gst&q=transpose+propertydescriptor&pli=1)), but it is a bit clumsy, and only really works if the data is all of the same type (since it expects a "column" to map to a "property"). And it is also very hard to add "rows" (since that is then properties).

But for array-like data, it can be done via data-binding and some smoke and mirrors.